# Is it possible to set up flow for nodejs with react-boilerplate?

Tags: flowtype, react-boilerplate

I don't have much experience with react-boilerplate nor webpack, but seems like it's not possible since the target is web. I've played around with the config of webpack, but had no success. Has anyone managed to set it up ? Any tips, links or examples would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with https://github.com/flowtype/flow-remove-types using flow-node instead of node.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). In the readme you can find a tutorial on [how to add flow](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-flow) to your project. Which is actually quite simple:

```
npm i -D flow-bin
```

Than add `"flow": "flow"` to your scripts in the `package.json` file

```
npm run flow init
```

To initialize the .flowconfig file

```
npm run flow
```

To start the flow server and also show the validation result. If you are using yarn, you don't need to add the `"flow": "flow"` to your scripts and just run the following commands:

```
yarn add -D flow-bin
yarn flow init
yarn flow
```

I don't recommend installing flow-bin globally, as you may use different flow versions for your projects, or your team. Also if you add it to the dependencies, everybody will install flow with the initial `npm install`

Comment: The question is how to use flow for the backend with react-boilerplate exclusively.  The solution is pretty simple https://github.com/flowtype/flow-remove-types. Thanks for the reply anyway :)

Comment: Ah, okey^^ My bad :/